# Grapqhql data is "undefined" when deconstructed, although the data is there

Tags: reactjs, graphql

The title says it. i tested the query on Playground and it works there. When i call it from the client i get the array of objects, but when i destructure them i get "undefined".

```
function UploadForm() {
    const { AuthUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const userId = AuthUser.id;
    const { id, url, path } = useQuery( FETCH_USERIMAGES_QUERY, {
        variables: {
          userId
        }
      });

    console.log("id: "+id);
    console.log(`url: ${url}`);
    console.log("path: "+path);
    

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Stuff</p>
        </div>
 
    )
}
```

And in the console i get:

```
id: undefined
url: undefined
path: undefined
```

I tried other ways:

```
function UploadForm() {
    const { AuthUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const userId = AuthUser.id;
    const { data: { getUserImages } } = useQuery( FETCH_USERIMAGES_QUERY, { // HERE
        variables: {
          userId
        }
      });

    const { id, url, path } = getUserImages; // HERE

    console.log(getUserImages); // HERE
    console.log("id: "+id);
    console.log(`url: ${url}`);
    console.log("path: "+path);


    return (
        <div>
            <p>Stuff</p>
        </div>

    )
}
```

And interestingly the console prints the array, including the data. But the deconstructed data remains undefined.

```
(2) […]
​
0: Object { id: "5fd27ff43b1e5b26984fd019", url: "http://localhost:5000/images/MZSjxjJ3vxao.jpg", path: "public/images/MZSjxjJ3vxao.jpg", … }
​
1: Object { id: "5fd27f431744b85b3848e4e6", url: "http://localhost:5000/images/oJaKB4CHQ1nD.jpg", path: "public/images/oJaKB4CHQ1nD.jpg", … }
​
length: 2
​
<prototype>: Array []
id: undefined
url: undefined
path: undefined
```

Weirdly when i do it this way, sometimes the page won't load at all, and i get the error: "TypeError: Object(...)(...).data is undefined", and it points to; data: { getUserImages }. I refresh a few times and it works and it console logs the array, and the unidentified data again, i refresh again and i get the error.

I have a query that does exactly the same that works fine, and prints the data fine. I have googled around and found similar issues, but none, where the arrays is actually fetchd, and no solutions.

Any idea why this does this?

Query

```
export const FETCH_USERIMAGES_QUERY = gql`
  query($userId: ID!){
    getUserImages(user: $userId){
      id
      url
      path
    }
  }
`;
```

With Loading:

```
function UploadForm() {
    const { AuthUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const userId = AuthUser.id;
    const { loading, data: { getUserImages } } = useQuery( FETCH_USERIMAGES_QUERY, {

        variables: {
          userId
        }
      });

    if(loading){
        console.log(loading)
    }else{
        const { id, url, path } = getUserImages;

        console.log(getUserImages);
        console.log("id: "+id);
        console.log(`url: ${url}`);
        console.log("path: "+path);
    }

    let uploadFormMarkup;
        if(loading){
            uploadFormMarkup = <p>Loading upload form</p>
        } else {
            const { id, url, path } = getUserImages;

            uploadFormMarkup = (
                <div>
                    <p>id: {id} </p>
                </div>
            );
        }
        return uploadFormMarkup;
}
```

Gets "TypeError: Object(...)(...).data is undefined". When working it prints the array in console, and deconstructed data remains undefined, like in above example. id in the div isn't printed either.

Last edit without deconstructing in the hook:

```
function UploadForm() {
    const { AuthUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const userId = AuthUser.id;
    const { loading, data } = useQuery( FETCH_USERIMAGES_QUERY, {

        variables: {
          userId
        }
      });

    if(loading){
        console.log(loading)
    }else{
        const { id, url, path } = data;

        console.log(data);
        console.log("id: "+id);
        console.log(`url: ${url}`);
        console.log("path: "+path);
    }

    let uploadFormMarkup;
        if(loading){
            uploadFormMarkup = <p>Loading upload form</p>
        } else {
            const { id, url, path } = data;

            uploadFormMarkup = (
                <div>
                    <p>id: {id} </p>
                </div>
            );
        }
        return uploadFormMarkup;
}
```

Deconstructed data still unidentified

Comment: follow docs, destructure after loading

Comment: Get the same result "TypeError: Object(...)(...).data is undefined"

Comment: update code in question

Comment: Updated at the bottom

Comment: still destructuring in hook declaration

Comment: You mean to do it like this:     const { loading, data } = useQuery( FETCH_USERIMAGES_QUERY Get the same result

Comment: ... but now `getUserImages` is undefined ?

Comment: Yes, i replaced it with data, that's what's getting the same result. I'll edit it in the post

Comment: `console.log(data)`  ... check network response ... no data as no authed client? ... and of course destructure from `data.getUserImages`

Comment: Console.log(data); gets the object with the array including objects with the data needed. console.log(id); still gets unidentified. Authed client is there, i checked. Console.log(data.getUserImages.id); also returns unidentified

Comment: if array then [0]? show logged `data`

Comment: It does: ​
0: Object { id: "5fd27ff43b1e5b26984fd019", url: "http://localhost:5000/images/MZSjxjJ3vxao.jpg", path: "public/images/MZSjxjJ3vxao.jpg", … }
​​
1: Object { id: "5fd27f431744b85b3848e4e6", url: "http://localhost:5000/images/oJaKB4CHQ1nD.jpg", path: "public/images/oJaKB4CHQ1nD.jpg", … }
​​
length: 2

Comment: data.getUserImages[0].id ?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it was needed to destructure data like this: **data.getUserImages[0].id**

Comment: some reason = structure of response ...  `const { id, url, path } = data.getUserImages[0];` (if you need only 1st image) as `getUserImages` returns an array - check API/server specs/type defs

Comment: Ahhhh that makes sense. Thanks again